# css animation working weird on explorer edge

Tags: css, css-animations

I've used animate.css library to create an animation - opening flower using classes rotateInDownLeft, rotateInDownRight and fadeIn. It works fine in chrome, opera and mozilla, but not in explorer edge. When I open a browser I just see my images (flower petals) arrive form different part of a screen like in powerpoint presentation.
I've made some tests without use of a library and it looks like the following code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotateInDownRight {
    from {
        -webkit-transform-origin: right bottom;
        transform-origin: right bottom;
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
        transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        -webkit-transform-origin: right bottom;
        transform-origin: right bottom;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes rotateInDownRight {
    from {
        -webkit-transform-origin: right bottom;
        transform-origin: right bottom;
        -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
        transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        -webkit-transform-origin: right bottom;
        transform-origin: right bottom;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}


#div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-animation: rotateInDownRight 2s;
    -moz-animation: rotateInDownRight 2s;
    -ms-animation: rotateInDownRight 2s;
    -o-animation: rotateInDownRight 2s;
    animation: rotateInDownRight 2s;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3cgmjazo/

results in strange behavior in explorer edge.
Instead of rotation/incline to right 45 degrees (like it behaves in chrome, ff, opera) its like arrive from the side of a screen. 
I would appreciate any help or advice how to solve this issue.

Comment: Remove vendor prefixes -ms-animation.

Comment: do not help... that was the first I tried to

Comment: Try caniuse.com for vendor prefixes.